# Detect favicon not found - Google S2 Favicon

Tags: javascript, html, favicon

If Google S2 favicon service can't find a favicon of a website, it returns a default image. I want to know that the favicon was not found so I can show some other default image (on my server), or switch to another favicon service (like g.etfv.co). I know Google S2 isn't exactly nice.

I need to do this in browser so HTML/JavaScript solutions would be nice.
I will always have root url, e.g. www.google.com or www.facebook.com.

**Final question** : How to detect favicon not found with Google S2, or should I switch to another favicon provider?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I need this have you come across any JS in browser solution?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code do this (as a wp plugin)

It checks for each of the favicon providers if the default image is provided. If so: then jump to the next provider. If none of the providers give me an image I will do a curl myself and e.g. also follow redirects and scan 404's for favicon.

I check it on the datastring returned: if this is equal to the "empty image" as provided by the specific provider, then uhm... it is an empty image (and yes if the provider changes his default image then need to change the variable of the empty-image-string)

e.g. for google it is (MD5):

```
private $_default = 'b8a0bf372c762e966cc99ede8682bc71';
```

Full source code (GPL): http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-favicons/trunk/  (under /includes/server you will find the plugins to do the http requests , parse the images etc...)

I decided to implement it in a plugin way:

- plugins to add providers (sources)
- plugins to further operate on the images (e.g. rescale, etc...)
- plugins to provide default favicons if none are found e.g. gravatars
- plugins to perform caching

it is implemented as a server and a client, so you can also install the server part and then do calls to the server via http xml requests: you send a piece of text and get the text returned with all hrefs replaced with hrefs + favicon in front of it.

Comment: I need to check in the browser with JS any thoughts?